# Данные MutableLiveData из Spinner возвращают null

Tags: java, mvvm, android-spinner, android-data-binding

Я использую паттерн MVVM и DataBinding в своём проекте. Передать значения в Spinner мне удалось, но вот получить из оттуда - проблема. Гуглил, но ни один способ мне не помог. Вот как я делаю:

1. Установил атрибут android:selectedItemPosition="@={viewModel.position}" для Spinner
2. Создал public static MutableLiveData position поле во ViewModel
3. Создал геттер и сеттер для этого поля
4. Создал InverseBindingAdapter

   ```
   @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:selectedItemPosition") 
   public MutableLiveData<Integer> SelectedItem(Spinner spinner) { 
       position.setValue(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
       return position;
   }
   ```

Данные обновляются (при перевороте устанавливаются предыдущие значения в Spinner), но не могу получить данные из LiveData: при дебаге видно, что данные с позицией поступают со Spinner, но position.getValue() возвращает null.
Вот класс handler, где я пытаюсь получить данные:

```
public static class DetailToStockActivityHandler {

    Intent intent;

    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btSave:
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), getPosition().getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case R.id.btCancel:
                view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(), MenuActivity.class));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```